# Rack::Test PUT method with JSON fails to convert JSON to params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rest, cucumber, rspec-rails

I am currently using rails 3.1.3, cucumber-rails 1.2.1, rspec-rails 2.8.1, and json_spec 0.8.0. I am building a restful web service API that will be used by an Android app. I am using TDD / BDD practices and have been able to successfully test web service actions with get() and post() in my Cucumber step definitions. However, when using put(), I ran into an issue.

Here is my device_update.feature:

```
Feature: Updating a Device
  The web service should accept a PUT request to update device settings.

  Scenario: The device information is updated when valid data is posted to the web service.
    Given a device exists
    When I put "/services/devices/4A3CABD4C4DE6E9F.json" with:
      """
      {
        "device": {
          "carrier": "SPRINT"
        }
      }
      """    
    Then the JSON should be:
      """
      {
        "message": "Device updated.",
        "response_code": 1
      }
      """
```

My step definition is:

```
When /^I get "([^"]*)"$/ do |path|
  get(path)
end

When /^I post to "([^"]*)" with:$/ do |path, json_string|
  post(path, json_string, {"CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"})
end

When /^I put "([^"]*)" with:$/ do |path, json_string|
  put(path, json_string, {"CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"})
end
```

When the test is run, I get the following:

```
When I put "/services/devices/4A3CABD4C4DE6E9F.json" with:
  """
  {
    "device": {
      "carrier": "SPRINT"
    }
  }
  """
  You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
  You might have expected an instance of Array.
  The error occurred while evaluating nil.[] (NoMethodError)
  ./app/controllers/services/devices_controller.rb:75:in `update'
  ./features/step_definitions/request_steps.rb:10:in `/^I put "([^"]*)" with:$/'
  features/services/devices/device_update.feature:7:in `When I put "/services/devices/4A3CABD4C4DE6E9F.json" with:'
Then the JSON should be:
  """
  {
    "message": "Device updated.",
    "response_code": 1
  }
  """
```

When I look at the log, I see the following:

```
Started PUT "/services/devices/4A3CABD4C4DE6E98.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-25 11:36:16 -0800
Processing by Services::DevicesController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"{\n  \"device\": {\n    \"carrier\": "SPRINT"\n  }\n}"=>nil, "id"=>"4A3CABD4C4DE6E98"}
```

I truncated the active record calls as they are not relevant.  It's obvious that the JSON is not being converted into proper parameters and this is why I'm getting an unexpected nil.

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass a string to `put`. It takes care of the conversion into a JSON string, which is generally a good thing. What is happening here is that your JSON string is *JSONified* again by `put`.

You should parse the JSON string first and pass the resulting object to `put`:

```
When /^I put "([^"]*)" with:$/ do |path, json_string|
  payload = JSON.parse(json_string)
  put(path, payload, {"CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"})
end
```

Also the content-type is probably unnecessary.

Comment: I'm curious why I would need to take this approach with put() when post() works fine like this: 

    `When /^I post to "([^"]*)" with:$/ do |path, json_string|
      post(path, json_string, {"CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"})
    end`

The two methods in rack-test seem to be doing the same thing, but the JSON is automagically parsed in post() but not put()?

Comment: It's not totally clear to me but I think it's related to how Rack is handling the request and its contents.

Comment: It works but it doesn't feel like I'm actually testing the app's ability to accept JSON code via a PUT. My solution so far has simply been to rewrite the routes so they use POST in place of PUT and DELETE. Not the best, but easier to test.